# Accordion layout with search option in extjs

Tags: java, search, extjs

I am designing FAQ page and I want to add search option to faq page

```
xtype: 'panel',
cls: 'FAQPanel',
layout: 'accordion',
title: 'Questions',
```

I am using same code from below website

https://github.com/bjornharrtell/extjs/blob/master/templates/admin-dashboard/classic/src/view/pages/FAQ.js

Can you please help me to add search option to this faq page ?

Comment: can you provided your efforts what you have tried?

Comment: Thank for reply.. I completed this one